# List all feature classes but exclude those which start with a certain character

Tags: arcpy

I would like to list all the feature classes of my SDE database, except those who starts with the letter M.

Any ideas please ?

```
import arcpy
fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
for fc in fcs
    print (fc)
```

Answer (score 3):

Given your code you could just check to see if the first character starts with M.

```
fcs = ['databasename.schema.aaa','databasename.schema.Mmm']
for fc in fcs:
    if fc.split('.')[-1][0] != 'M':
        print(fc.split('.')[-1])
```

Of course you could use wildcards [as described here](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/functions/listfeatureclasses.htm) but this is not case sensitive.

Comment: Thank you fot you answer, i actually forgot to mention that it's an enterprise database, so all the feature classes are prefixed by the name of the database and also the name of the schema; giving something like this : databasename.schema.FeraureClasseName. and  i would like to exclude the featureclasses where the FeatureClasseName starts with a certain caracter.

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I strongly encourage you to use [Walk - ArcGIS Pro | Documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/data-access/walk.htm) instead of the legacy ArcPy functions for listing geospatial data.

```py
import arcpy
import os

ws = # path to workspace, which can be an SDE file
walk = arcpy.da.Walk(ws, datatype="FeatureClass")
for root, dirs, files in walk:
    for f in files:
        if f.split(".")[-1].upper().startswith("M"):
            continue
        print(os.path.join(root, f).replace(ws, ""))
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to GBG's code, you may need to add a different piece of code for features inside a feature dataset.
The following example includes a snippet that handles these by looping through all the feature datasets.

```
import arcpy
import os
 
arcpy.env.workspace = "xxxx"
 
for FD in arcpy.ListDatasets():
   print '\n' + FD + '\n' 
       for fc in fcs:
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, it's very helpful.